# Как в Visual Studio 2013 добавить кнопку?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Где эти панели, чтоб перетащил кнопку, кликнул по ней и прописал код, как в старом добром бейсике 6.0?   
Ох уж этот бейсик 6.0. Не придумали еще программу лучше тебя...

Comment: какие панели? о чем вы вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio может работать с четырьмя разными языками + к каждому есть несколько видов проектов. В зависимости от проекта, студия располагает различными инструментами. Поэтому уточняйте, с чем работать собираетесь.

Методом научного тыка и дедукции, я так полагаю язык Visual Basic .NET и проект Windows Forms Application? Тогда так: View -> Toolbox (ctrl+alt+x)